# datatables order column for uk date and time

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I am trying to sort a column in a table via the DataTables pluing that has a UK date and time like this: 21/09/2013 11:15

Using the code from Ronan Guilloux:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "uk_date-pre": function ( a ) {
        if ($.trim(a) != '') {
            var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        } else {
            var x = 10000000000000; // = l'an 1000 ...
        }

        return x;
    },

    "uk_date-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "uk_date-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

and also ive added this code to detect it automatically so i don't have to set which column it is for:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
    function ( sData )
    {
        if (sData !== null && sData.match(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4} (0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5]\d)$/))
        {
            //console.log(sData);
            return 'uk_date';
        }
        return null;
    }
);
```

The problem i have is that although i can see the regex is matching the string it is not then calling the 'uk_date-pre', 'uk_date-asc' or 'uk_date-desc' can anyone explain why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with it for some time i had to abandon the regEx and i simply added this to the set up:

```
aoColumnDefs: [{ "sType": "datetime-uk", "aTargets": [whichCol] }]
```

I then set the whichCol var to either null or a column number if it was on the page that needed this UK sorting.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this.

The code from Ronan Guilloux will work as expected if you change :

```
var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
```

to:

```
var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1]) * 1;
```

The reason being that we are dealing with "21/09/2013 11:15" therefore

```
var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
```

will only populate frTimea[0]  and frTimea[1]...